# Trigger notification from SQL Server database to an asp.net app

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, react-native, push-notification

How can a notification be triggered for changes to data in a table called `tblProducts` as defined below  in  a SQL Server database?

This notification will make the consuming asp.net app send a notification to a react native mobile app.

The following conditions apply to the notification.

1. This notification will be consumed by an asp.net app that uses the same database.
2. The notification should be triggered whenever a new product is added to this table or an existing product is modified.
3. The notification should simply mention whether a product by a certain name has been changed or added. For example, `Product Xyz has been changed` or `Product Abc has been added`.

*Table definition*

```
  CREATE TABLE  dbo.tblProducts (
            ProductId INT  PRIMARY KEY,
             ProductName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
             ProductDescription VARVHAR(MAX),
             VendorId INT,
             CurrentInventory INT,
             CreateDate DATETIME,
             LastChangeDate DATETIME       
     );
```

Comment: you can use this library for signalR https://github.com/olofd/react-native-signalr or you can check onesignal as well

Comment: Yeah it all depends on your existing architecture, so try out few of these before choosing one

Comment: I have edited the original question so it's no more an opinion based question. Is there no way to open this question even after making it more specific?  Or I should just post a new question that will be duplicate of this edited question? Please let me know if any moderator is seeing this.

Answer (score 1):

This completely depends upon your requirement. But, I would recommend going with Firebase.